# Reverse Engineering a LINQ Statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to reverse engineer a LINQ statement, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
bool isAllUnchecked = !lvTech.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(lvItem => lvItem.Checked);
```

My progress so far;

```
bool isAllUnchecked = true;
foreach(ListviewItem item in lvTech.Items)
{
    if(item.checked)
    {
      isAllUnchecked = false;
    }
}
```

I'm using Resharper and its' convert to LINQ didn't show up so far. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `Any()` has an early out

Comment: I'm trying to create the case that Resharper shows up and converts my foreach statement into the given LINQ statement.

Comment: A bug in your "progress" and the two answers: it should be `foreach(ListViewItem ...`.

Comment: Similarly, seeing as you're using the case sensitive C#, it's `.Checked` throughout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
bool isAllUnchecked = false; // Variable name doesn't fit what you're doing
                             // Don't forget to change.
foreach(ListViewItem item in lvTech.Items)
{
    if(item.checked)
    {
      isAllUnchecked = true;
      break;
    }
}
```

`Any()` checks if there's any item that satisfies the condition, if so it returns `true`.

And you should rename your variable `isAnyChecked` or you should negate the result of the query.

Comment: It negates the result does it not?

Comment: `isAllUnchecked = false` was correct, but the break makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Although bool declaration will be true and will be set to false in if statement. My LINQ statement has ! at the start

Comment: As the OP is trying to reverse engineer the original Linq code, `foreach(var ...` corresponds more closely to no `.Cast` call.

Comment: @MarkHurd Could you explain why it corresponds to no `.Cast` call?

Comment: Just reverted back the change, I'm wondering how the cast operation works exactly when you use `var`, though.

Comment: @hattenn `foreach(var item in items)` means the compiler chooses the type, `T`, from whatever `IEnumerable<T>` `items` is, just like `items.Any(...)` would. `foreach(ListviewItem item in items)` means _ignore_ whatever `items` enumerates and always cast it to `ListviewItem`, just like `.Cast<ListViewItem>()`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the right loop (at least it is what the variable name suggests):

```
bool isAllUnchecked = true;
foreach(ListviewItem item in lvTech.Items)
{
    if(item.checked)
    {
      isAllUnchecked = false;
      break;
    }
}
```

This is the same with LINQ:

```
bool isAllUnchecked = lvTech.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                  .All(lvItem => !lvItem.Checked);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is correct indeed but I think you oversaw the ! at the start of the LINQ expression :)

Comment: @user1595357: the Linq query was ok, i prefer  `Enumerable.All` with a variable `isAllUnchecked `. But the break was missing in the `foreach`. Both, `Any` and `All` break immediately.